# What are differential equations and how do you solve ${dy \over dx}=y$ and find $y$ in terms $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function, chain-rule

I had been wondering about how to solve the equation $${dy \over dx}=y$$. My progress was to use the chain rule, like setting $$z=2x\;{dy\over dx}={dy\over dz}*{dz\over dx}={dy\over d(2x)}*2=y.$$ Now I’m officially stuck. What am I supposed to do?
**An answer that do work(just for checking):** $e^{x+1}$

Comment: e$^x$ also works

Comment: $\int {dy \over y} = \int dx$

Comment: it's variable separable  ODE also linear .

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know that.

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR ANSWERS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a separable differential equation. Assuming $y\ne0$ which is a condition we will check separately, divide both sides of the equation by $y$:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=y\\
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=1\\
\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}\,dx=\int\,dx\\
\int\frac{1}{y}\,dy=x+C_1\\
\ln{|y|}+C_2=x+C_1\\
\ln{|y|}=x+C_1-C_2\\
\ln{|y|}=x+C_3\\
|y|=e^{x+C_3}\\
y=\pm e^{C_3}e^{x}
$$

$\pm e^{C_3}$ covers all real numbers except $0$. But $y=0$ is also a solution because $0'=0$. Therefore, we can write the following as the general solution to this equation:

$$y=Ce^x,\ C\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{y}=dx\Rightarrow\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int dx$

$\Rightarrow \ln\left(y\right)=x+C\Rightarrow y=e^{x+C}=C'e^x$

$C$ and $C'=e^{C}$ are constants; in order to put integrals, you should quote the theorem of separation of variables for differential equations.

Comment: I corrected $C’e$ to $C’e^x$

Comment: My mistake typing it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a solution without "magical" manipulation of differentials.

Assuming that $y \neq 0$ on some interval, divide the equation with $y$:
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} = 1.$$

Now the left hand side can be written as the derivative of $\ln |y(x)|$ and the right hand side as the derivative of $x$:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln |y(x)| = \frac{d}{dx} x.$$

Therefore, $\ln |y(x)| = x + C,$ where $C$ is some constant, and on the interval we thus have
$$y(x) = \pm e^{x+C} = \pm e^C e^x = C' e^x,$$
where $C' = \pm e^C$ is a nonzero constant.

We can see though that also when $C' = 0,$ we get a solution: $y(x) \equiv 0.$ We therefore have a general solution $y(x) = C' e^x,$ where $C'$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The first question in your title is

> What are differential equations?

The informal answer is that often what we know about a quantity we are interested in is its rate of change. For example, if you know  the velocity  as a function $v(t)$ of time you can find the position $p$  by solving the differential equation
$$
p'(t) = v(t) .
$$
That's just integration. You use any known position to find the "constant of integration".

The differential equation you ask about,
$$
y' = y,
$$
says that the rate of change of $y$ is $y$ itself. In slightly more generality
$$
y' = ky
$$
says that the rate of change of $y$ is proportional to $y$. That classic equation  models population growth over time or compound interest: the more stuff there is the faster it's growing. The solution is exponential growth:
$$
y = Ce^{kt}.
$$

The second order differential equation
$$
y" = -ky
$$
models a spring: the second derivative of position is (essentially) a force (that's Newton's law $F=ma$). The equation says that the farther $y$ is from $0$ the greater the force returning it to $0$. The solutions are the oscillating functions $y = \sin(t+ \phi)$.